# Php session not working if php tag is not the first thing in the file

Tags: php

Everything works fine in local but when I uploaded the code on the sideground hosting the sessions stopped working and after 1 day I figured why.
if the <?php tag is no the first thing in the file then the session wont work and I was wondering why?

```
 <?php
    session_start();

    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

this is the code that doesn't work

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IU5gI.png)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

and this is the working code, I've just deleted the space before <?php and now it's working.

[Here again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQOlb.png)

Does anyone know why it's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because sessions modify HTTP headers, and headers must be sent before HTTP body (what you generate with php)
Therefore there can't be any content outputted before a session_start.

In your example the simple "space" before the <?php tag is like a echo "Huge Content".

Comment: Ok but when I've tested the website on my pc it worked fine why is that?

Comment: It may be an encoding problem (utf8 / latin1 ) or CR/LF ( new line) that differ in local than in the hosting site